# Depicting a Single Equation Error Correction Model in Matrix / Vector notation?

Tags: regression, matrix, vector-autoregression, notation, vector-error-correction-model

I am trying to express the following single equation error correction model in matrix / vector notation. The original model is:

$
\Delta Y =  y_{t-1} \delta_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{k}z_{i,t-1} \delta_k + \sum_{i=1}^{p} \Delta z_{i,t-i} \kappa + t \tau + \epsilon $

which is then in matrix notation:

$
\Delta Y = z_{t-1} \delta + W \kappa + t \tau + \epsilon = V \gamma + D \theta + \epsilon
$

in which gamma describes the linear combination of the common long-term trend and the adjustment speed to this trend. kappa describes the short term dynamics.

With:
$
\Delta Y$  is $ (n \times 1),z_0 = y_{t-1} \
z_{t-1} = (-z_0; z_{t-1} \dots z_{k;t-1})$ is  $(1 \times (k+1)=K), \
\delta $  is $ \left(((k+1)=K) \times 1\right), \
W = (\Delta z_t, \Delta z_{t-1}, \dots, \Delta z_{t-p}), $  where $ \Delta z_t $ is $ (n \times 1), $  thus $ W $ is  $(n \times K(p+1)), $ for  t=1, $\dots, n, \
V = (z_{t-1}; W) $  is $ (n \times (K+K(p+1))), \
\gamma = (\delta, \kappa) $ is $ (K+K(p \times 1) \times 1), \
D = (n \times b) \ \text{including deterministic exogenous variables}, \
\theta = (1 \times b), \
\epsilon$  is $ (n \times 1).
$

Is this somehow correct? Any suggestions on how to improve it?